# How to align 1 to 2 boxes in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align a one to two form elements with rest of the form but I'm having problem while trying to do it. I'm getting the output below

[image]

But I want to get the output below ("Genel açıklamalar" section is on the track)

[image]

How could I manage to do it? I try to do it by HTML below but weirdly, not working. (Also, I'm using Angular)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <strong><div class="text-danger">Makam Olur Tarihi</div></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="date" name="prmMakamOlurTarihi" class="form-control m-input" #searchDate>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <strong><div class="text-danger">Rapor Tarihi</div></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <input type="date" name="prmRaporTarihi" class="form-control m-input" #searchDate>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <label style="text-align: left;"><strong>Genel Açıklamalar</strong></label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <textarea name="textarea" maxlength="500" class="form-control m-input"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <strong>Raporu Düzenleyen Kişi</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <input name="prmRaporuDuzenleyenKisi" class="form-control m-input" maxlength="20" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <strong>Raporu Düzenleyen Kişinin Ünvanı</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <input name="prmRaporuDuzenleyenKisininUnvani" maxlength="20" class="form-control m-input" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: The only difference I see in the two images is the first black label being shifted a bit. Is that what you're asking about? Also, the output of the code above doesn't match the image. Please revise to show the problem accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this solution will work for you...

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <strong>
                    <div class="text-danger">Makam Olur Tarihi</div>
                </strong>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="date" name="prmMakamOlurTarihi" class="form-control m-input" #searchDate>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <strong>
                    <div class="text-danger">Rapor Tarihi</div>
                </strong>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="date" name="prmRaporTarihi" class="form-control m-input" #searchDate>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label style="text-align: left;"><strong>Genel Açıklamalar</strong></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <textarea name="textarea" maxlength="500" class="form-control m-input"></textarea>
            </div>

            
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <strong>Raporu Düzenleyen Kişi</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <input name="prmRaporuDuzenleyenKisi" class="form-control m-input" maxlength="20" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <strong>Raporu Düzenleyen Kişinin Ünvanı</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <input name="prmRaporuDuzenleyenKisininUnvani" maxlength="20" class="form-control m-input" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```